# How to ensure Spark use the number of set executors is used across every stage?

Tags: apache-spark

I've found that some intermediate stages use (much) fewer number of executors than the value of `spark.executor.instances`.

Currently, `spark.executor.instances` is set with `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` is set to false

We've also tried enabling `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` to true and set `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` to some value.

But, in both scenarios, `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` and `spark.executor.instances` seem to be ignored.

I wonder if anyone has any pointer on how to investigate further or what might be a root cause.

Edit: when the dynamic allocation is enabled, we also set `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

> spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors

Comment: I did. Let me edit a question to clarify that.